# KendoUI How can we generate button to clear data near a field (in a popup)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have popup in a grid. when I click the popup button I have fields (kendo datepicker) now I want to put a button just near the calendar logo int the same line . 
How can I do that any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: I think it would help to see the relevant code.

Comment: I have a png but i can't post it because I'm new here. However the code is similar to this demo : http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

Comment: any idea, responses to this issue ?